# Points Where Slope is Zero

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Problem:

> Find the coordinates of any point on the curve of $y^2-4xy=x^2+5$ for which the tangent is horizontal.

When I solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$, I end up getting $x=-2y$. So then I was thinking that I can put in any number for $x$ and get a corresponding $y$ where $(x,y)$ is a point where the slope is zero. So I plugged in $1$ for $x$ and got $-\frac{1}{2}$ for $y$, which is the point $(1,-\frac{1}{2})$. But this point can't be a point where the slope is zero because graphically the slope is zero only at $(2,-1)$ and $(-2,1)$. What am I missing?

Comment: Might be worth graphing to see what is going on.  $y^2 -4xy = x^2 + 5$ is a hyperbola.  $x =-2y$ is line that intersects the hyperbola at two points.  According to our calculations these points of intersection are the only place where the tangent slope is $0$.  But the *other* points of the line, the ones *not* on the hyperbola are.... utterly irrelevant.  That $x=-2y$ is a requirement for a point of the hyperbola to have a horizontal tangent but it is not the *only* requirement.  It is also a requirement that... the point *be* on the hyperbola in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting $x =-2y$ you also have to take into account the fact that $y^{2}-4xy=x^{2}+5$ because you have to find points ** on the curve** at which the derivative is $0$. If you solve these two equations simultaneously you will get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$(y-2x)^2-5x^2=5$$

WLOG $y-2x=\sqrt5\sec t,x=\tan t$

Differentiating both sides wrt $x$

$$2(y-2x)(y_1-2)=10x\implies y_1-2=\dfrac{5x}{y-2x}=\dfrac{5\tan t}{\sqrt5\sec t}=\sqrt5\sin t$$

We need $y_1=0$

$$\implies\sin t=-\dfrac2{\sqrt5}\implies\cos t=\pm\dfrac1{\sqrt5}\implies x=\tan t=?$$

Answer (score 1):

You forget that you need $y^2 -4xy =x^2 +5$ for the point to even be *on* the curve,  as well as $x = -2y$ for the slope to equal $0$.  You can't just put in *any* number for $x$ and solve $x=-2y$ because that point $(x, -\frac 12x)$ might not even be on the curve.

And indeed if $x =1$ and $y = -\frac 12$ we do *NOT* get $(-\frac 12)^2 - 4*1*(-\frac 12)  = 1^2 + 5$.  I'm not even going to do the math.  I *know* it won't work.  So $(1, -\frac 12)$ is *not* a point on the curve.  It doesn't *matter* that $1 = -2(-\frac 12)$. It's not a point on the curve so it can't be a tangent point.

So to solve you must plug $x = -2y$ back into $y^2 -4xy =x^2 +5$ to get $y^2 - 4(-2y)y = (-2y)^2 + 5$ and solve for $y$ and then solve fro $x = -2y$.  That will give us a point on the curve *and* it will be a point where the tangent line has $0$ slope.

Answer (score 0):

You should take care that the point lies on the curve. All the corresponding values of x and y for $x=-2y$ won't satisfy $y^2-4xy=x^2+5$

Solving both equations simultaneously-

$$x=-2y$$
$$y^2+8y^2=4y^2+5$$
$$5^2y=5$$
$$y=+-1$$ $$x=+-2$$

The required points are $(2,-1)(-2,1)$

Answer (score 0):

After solving for $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 $  you got $x=-2y$, Now you have condition all the set of values of $x$ that satisfy $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 $, Now you need to solve for the values by subsituting the values back into the equation of the curve.

$y^2−4xy=x^2+5$ , as $x = -2y$ we have:

$y^2-4(-2y)(y) = (-2y)^{2}+5$

Solving this quadtratic equation will yeild the answers.

Answer (score -1):

as you get x = -2y so it will satisfy the given function, 
putting x = -2y in given equation

y^2 + 8y^2 = 4y^2 +5
5y^2 = 5
y^2 = 1
y = -1 and 1
and corresponding values of x will be 2 and  -2
so pints will be (-2,1) and (2,-1)